# Are there any adblockers for Safari that work?

Tags: ad-blocker, safari

Requirements: Blocks at least the ads in front of YouTube videos

Answer (score 0):

[AdGuard](https://adguard.com/en/adguard-mac/overview.html) - Freeware. There's also a paid version, but I've never tried it.
It does sometimes let an ad through when you first visit, but you just refresh the page & it's gone. You don't have to play it, you just see a still. YouTube are constantly fighting the ad blockers, so periodically they will win for a week, then an update will fix it.

I haven't actually seen an advert on anything since I got this several years ago. I sometimes forget just how many ads there are… brought back every time I use someone else's computer.

Alternatively, there's [AdBlock](https://getadblock.com/en/), also freeware. I used to swap between them if one was going through a period of being beaten by the advertisers, but I haven't swapped back to this in a year or so.